# How to combine multiple columns into one long column using python and pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hi everyone I am currently working on data like the following:
[Example of original data file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHnMg.png)

There are a total of 51 files, each with more than 800 oscillating columns, e.g. (Time, ID, x1, x2, ID, x1, x2,...), the columns are all unlabelled. Within the file, each row has different numbers of columns, something looks like this:[Shape of one data file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWoRn.jpg)

I need to merge all 51 files into one file, and then stack the columns vertically like this:
[Example of output file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MjTj.png)

So for each timestamp, each student will have a specific row with their location x,y.

Can anyone please help me with this, thanks

I used the following code to merge CSV files with different columns, but the output file is twice the size of the originals (e.g. 100MB VS 50MB). My approach was to combine the files using the maximum number of columns and expand to each row. However, this approach created a lot of missing values in the data, and thus, increasing the size of output files.

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

def concatenate(indir="C:\Test Files",outfile="F:\Research Assitant\PROJECT_Position Data\Test File\Concatenate.csv"):
    os.chdir(indir)
    fileList=glob.glob("*.csv")
    dfList=[]
    for filename in fileList:
        ### Loop over each line
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            ### Skip first four lines
            for _ in range(4):
                next(f)
            ### Get the numbers of columns in each line
            col_count = [ len(l.split(",")) for l in f.readlines() ]

        ### Read the current csv file
        df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, delimiter=",", names=range(max(col_count)), 
                         skiprows=4, keep_default_na=False, na_values=[""])
        ### Append to the list
        dfList.append(df)

    concatDf=pd.concat(dfList,axis=0)
    concatDf.to_csv(outfile,index=None)
```

Is there any way to reduce the size of the output files? Or a more efficient way to deal with heterogeneous CSV files in python?

And how do I stack the columns vertically after merged all the CSV files?

Answer (score 0):

```
    with open(os.path.join(working_folder, file_name)) as f:
    student_data = []
    for line in f:
        row = line.strip().split(",")
        number_of_results = round(len(row[1:]) / 4) # if we do not count time column, data repeats every 4 times
        time_column = row[0]
        results = row[1:]
        for i in range(number_of_results):
            data = [time_column] + results[i*4: (i+1)*4]
            student_data.append(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(student_data, columns=["Time", "ID", "Name", "x1", "x2"])
df
```

Comment: Hi griggy, thanks for your help. I am so sorry that I didn't make my question very clear. I just updated the question with more details. Again, thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Freashpythoner. I changed my code to work with the updated requirements. The code above will process a single file (it will work with any format - as described by you). You can loop thru the list of your files and keep concatenating them to the dataframe. Please let me know if you have any questions.